# Nested GridView parent-grid checkbox checked all on child-grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net

**Solution:** I end up using server side control since I could not find anything on the Internet to solve my problem.

I have a nested GridView with gvSelect as the parent-grid and gvSelectExpand as the child-grid. **Goal** - What I am trying to achieve is when I checked one checkbox on gvSelect, all checkbox in the gvSelectExpand under that row (the child-grid of that row) will be checked with a client side control.

I have a javascript that will checked all visible checkbox in the header, but I am looking for something much smaller. Can someone help me out? Thanks.

**JavaScript** - checked all checkbox

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function select_deselectAll(chkVal, idVal) {
        var frm = document.forms[0];
        // Loop through all elements
        for (i = 0; i < frm.length; i++) {
            // Look for our Header Template's Checkbox
            if (idVal.indexOf('chkbxSelectAll') != -1) {
                // Check if main checkbox is checked, then select or deselect datagrid checkboxes 
                if (chkVal == true) {
                    frm.elements[i].checked = true;
                }
                else {
                    frm.elements[i].checked = false;
                }
                // Work here with the Item Template's multiple checkboxes
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**JavaScript** - expand nested grid

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
            $(this).attr("src", "Images/minus.png");
        });
        $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "Images/plus.png");
            $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
        });
    </script>
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSelect" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvSelect_DataBound" 
              BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ItemNumber">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField Visible="False" DataField="RecordUID" SortExpression="RecordUID" HeaderText="RecordUID" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="Images/plus.png" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlSelectExpand" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvSelectExpand" runat="server" Width="350px" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Slab">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectExpand" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slab" SortExpression="Slab" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Slab" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Size" SortExpression="Size" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Size" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sqft" SortExpression="Sqft" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Sqft" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Block" SortExpression="Block" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Block" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Totalweight" SortExpression="Totalweight" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Totalweight" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxSelectAll" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="XX-Small" Text="Select All Slabs"
                              onclick="javascript: return select_deselectAll (this.checked, this.id);" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Bundle" SortExpression="Bundle" ReadOnly="True" 
            HeaderText="Bundle" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemNumber" SortExpression="ItemNumber" 
            ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="ItemNumber" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemDescription" SortExpression="ItemDescription" 
            ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="ItemDesc" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="whse" SortExpression="whse" ReadOnly="True" 
            HeaderText="Warehouse" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NumSlabs" SortExpression="NumSlabs" ReadOnly="True" 
            HeaderText="NumSlabs" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QtyTiedUp" SortExpression="QtyTiedUp" ReadOnly="True" 
            HeaderText="QtyTiedUp" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Define "much smaller"? Does your current code work or not?

Comment: @VDWWD my code currently does work, but I am looking for a function that checks all child-grid of that certain row